# Pegar texto dentro de uma lista <ul> PHP

Tags: php, html, classes

Olá, estou criando um projeto que preciso pegar uns textos dentro de uma lista em outro site, vou mostrar como eu preciso;

Estou usando o `file_get_contents`;

```
$url = "www.site.com";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$getTextoList = "";
preg_match_all($getTextoList, $html, $GetTexto);
$GetTexto = str_replace(" ", ", ", $$GetTexto[1][0]);
```

No site tem uma lista assim:

```
<div class="listdoTexto">
<ul>                                                                    
<li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto</a></li>
<li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto</a></li>
<li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto</a></li>
<li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Eu queria pegar apenas o **"texto"** que esta entre `<a></a>` dessa lista.

Comment: Acho que isto pode te ajudar: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: @thiagoalessio Tem algum exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a regex no `preg_match_all`:

```
|<div class="listdoTexto">[\w\W]*<\/ul>|
```

Onde `[\w\W]*` irá pegar qualquer caractere entre `<div class="listdoTexto">` e `<\/ul>`:

```
\w -> qualquer caractere alfanumérico e underscore "_")
\W -> qualquer caractere NÃO alfanumérico e underscore "_")
*  -> uma ou quantas ocorrências houverem entre o último </ul> até <div class="listdoTexto">
```

Isso irá me retornar uma Array no índice `[0]`, onde contém o resultado que desejo. Neste caso converto a Array em string com `implode`:

```
$GetTexto = implode(",", $GetTexto[0]);
```

Porém podemos ter um problema se houver mais lista no HTML. Exemplo:

```
         |→ <div class="listdoTexto">
         |    <ul>
Só quero |       <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto1</a></li>
pegar    |       <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto2</a></li>
esta     |       <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto3</a></li>
parte... |       <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto4</a></li>
         |→    </ul>
            </div>

           <div class="listdoTexto2">
              <ul>                
..mas o          <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto5</a></li>
regex irá          <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto6</a></li>
até aqui →    </ul>
           </div>
```

Ou seja, o resultado do `$GetTexto` após o `implode` seria isto:

```
<div class="listdoTexto">
   <ul>
      <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto1</a></li>
      <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto2</a></li>
      <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto3</a></li>
      <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="listdoTexto2">
   <ul>
      <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto5</a></li>
      <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto6</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Como eu quero pegar somente até o primeiro `</ul>`, posso usar `substr` com `strpos`:

```
$GetTexto = substr($GetTexto, 0, strpos($GetTexto, "</ul>"));
```

O resultado agora é esse:

```
<div class="listdoTexto">
   <ul>
      <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto1</a></li>
      <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto2</a></li>
      <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto3</a></li>
      <li class="texto"><a href="textolink">texto4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Como só quero o texto, uso `strip_tags` para eliminar as tags:

```
$GetTexto = strip_tags($GetTexto);
```

Irá retornar somente o texto, mas com quebra de linha e possíveis espaços antes,  depois ou entre os textos:

```
texto1
texto2
texto3
texto4
```

Posso usar `preg_replace` com `trim` para substituir as quebras de linha e os espaços indesejados por `,,`, que depois será usado posteriormente em um `replace`:

```
$GetTexto = preg_replace("/\s{2,}|\n/", ",,", trim($GetTexto));
```

Agora temos:

```
texto1,,texto2,,texto3,,texto4
```

Agora para separar os textos com vírgula e espaço, pode usar `str_replace` substituindo as `,,`:

```
$GetTexto = str_replace(",,", ", ", $GetTexto);
```

Resultado final:

```
texto1, texto2, texto3, texto4
```

> Apesar de chegar ao resultado final, não sei se essa seria a melhor
>   abordagem. Pode ser que haja um método usando [Document Object
>   Model](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) mais eficiente, mas espero que ajude.

**Código:**

```
$url = "http://www.site.com";
$html = file_get_contents($url);

$getTextoList = '|<div class="listdoTexto">[\w\W]*<\/ul>|';
preg_match_all($getTextoList, $html, $GetTexto);

$GetTexto = implode(",", $GetTexto[0]);
$GetTexto = substr($GetTexto, 0, strpos($GetTexto, "</ul>")); // 
$GetTexto = strip_tags($GetTexto);
$GetTexto = preg_replace("/\s{2,}|\n/", ",,", trim($GetTexto));
$GetTexto = str_replace(",,", ", ", $GetTexto);
```

**[Teste no Ideone](https://ideone.com/gchp3G)**

Comment: Pode me ajudar, eu estava recebendo um erro de SSL, então corrige colocando `$arrContextOptions=array(
 "ssl"=>array(
  "verify_peer"=>false,
  "verify_peer_name"=>false,
 ),
);` só que eu coloco a url e não recebo nada na input, onde coloquei para gerar esse valor.

Comment: `$html = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));`

Comment: Eu fiz alguns testes e o html estar vindo, mais á algo errado aqui:

Comment: `$GetTexto = implode(",", $GetTexto[0]);
 $GetTexto = substr($GetTexto, 0, strpos($GetTexto, "</ul>")); // 
 $GetTexto = strip_tags($GetTexto);
 $GetTexto = preg_replace("/\s{2,}|\n/", ",,", trim($GetTexto));
 $GetTexto = str_replace(",,", ", ", $GetTexto);`

Comment: Se tiver outras divs  na frente da div list também funciona?

Comment: Opa! Cara, funciona sim. O que deu errado?

Comment: Então, eu vi um coisa dentro do htmlt term `" "` e `' '` acho que esta com erro nessa parte.

Comment: Vou analisar aqui...

Comment: Olha aqui, preciso pegar essas tags do vídeo https://ideone.com/jyf99s

Comment: No Ideone a url tah errada, veja: https://w...content-available-to-author-only...s.com....

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75345/discussion-between-dvd-and-matheus-calixto).